Difference between {} as an object and {} as empty block scope in JS
I see different outputs for this statement
console.log({}+[])
some say it should be solved as an empty block followed by +[] which results in + ( array converted to an empty string ) and + making it 0 as a number, so the console output should be 0
on the other hand, I see all engines treating it as an empty object + empty string.

I don't know the specifics, but the context is important. let b =  is a really good indicator that it's an Object.

The only time when it matters is when a set of braces can be treated as a object literal or a block. When used as the RHS of an assignment or within any other expression, it will always be an object. Otherwise in the context of a statement, it will be treated as a block unless you were to wrap it in parentheses, it would then be treated as an object. (similar to how function declarations and function expressions are handled)

@ScottMarcus "the creation of objects with their own scope" - no. Object do not create a scope!

@ScottMarcus line 2 in the first code block does not create an object. Consider {} === {}; which should be false if it was comparing two objects. But in reality it's a syntax error because there is an empty block, then a === with no left-hand value for it. Check on https://astexplorer.net/ what a lone {} on a line is or even {foo:1} vs a = {}. Also, consider a function like f1 = () => {} vs f2 = () => ({})  - if {} was always an object, then f1() would not produce undefined. But it does.

"I see different outputs for this statement console.log({}+[])" - no. When {}+[] is the argument to a function call, it is always an expression that sums an object literal and an array literal, resulting in [object Object]. Only when evaluated as a statement of its own, like {}; +[];, it results in 0.

basically javascript differentiates objects from block scopes depending on the context where the brackets is, if it is expecting a value (such as an argument, or an variable) then it is an object, if it is not expecting a value and is after a control structure then it is a block scope.
I cannot be 100% sure about this, but it must be on the same logic that the javascript verifies if the is a syntax error on the code, just like: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
